# Twilio Monitor EventList sample code isn't working

Tags: twilio

I’m trying the example  #1: EventDate filtering using c# from this page:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/monitor-events

and it’s throwing a null reference exception on the “foreach” – i.e., events.Events was returned from ListEvents as  null. Events do exist within the date range I’ve selected.

Twilio (4.0.3), Twilio.Monitor (1.0.0) and RestSharp (105.0.1) have all been updated via nuget.

This sample code has been added in to an existing program that successfully sends & receives SMS messages.

The problem apparently has something to do with the date range filtering – if the code that sets the start & end date is simply commented out, the code works better – although there’s still an issue with the “Description” property being returned as a null.   At least the EventDate and EventType are valid.

Has anyone made EventList work with the date filter?  Any suggestions for how to proceed?

Comment: Twilio library maintainer here.  If you want to file a bug over here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp I can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Devin, I've added an issue report!

Answer (score 0):

From the [issue](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/174) referenced above regarding the [C# Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install).

> Your code is right, but you get this error because there aren't any
>   Events to be returned, and you're trying to loop through them.
>
> Change your loop to the following and it will stop error'ing when
>   there aren't any events.
>
> ```
> if (events.Events == null) return;
> foreach (var e in events.Events)
> {
>     Console.WriteLine(e.Description);
> }
> ```